# I dont understand this coding style in PHP

Tags: php, syntax

I have just a question... I'm seeing this coding style in various php scripts and don't understand what this means... Could someone explain me this^^

example code:

```
empty($config) OR $this->initialize($config);
```

or this

```
$url AND $this->create($url);
```

Comment: if you access $this->initialize($config) directly you could get undefined $config variable error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That about the OR operator : if 1st condition is true, then PHP won't bother to execute 2nd: knowing that the 1st is true is enough to return true.

You can do the same for and (except it's the opposite of course: if 1st condition is false, PHP won't interpret 2nd)

This

```
empty($config) OR $this->initialize($config);
```

Is a shortcut for

```
if ( ! empty($config)) { //(BTW I guess it should be if (empty($options)) no? )
    $this->initialize($config);
}
```

And

```
$url AND $this->create($url);
```

for

```
if ( ! $url) {
    $this->create($url);
```

Answer (score 3):

it's a way to perform null/true/false checks and conditionally execute some code ... so in short it's just a short form of if/then/else.

i would not stick to this kind of "short" notation since it blurs the line between real logical operations and program control flow

Answer (score 1):

It's a short-circuit aspect of php where in `OR`, if the first statement is true, the next one will be ignored, and for `AND`, if the first statement is false, the next one will be ignored

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

In your case, the first one says

> If $config is not empty, then initialize

the second one says

> if $url is set, then call a create method on the current object

Answer (score 0):

All such functions are very well answered at [php.net](http://www.php.net/). For eg, [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function, and

Looking at @haltabush 's answer, I think I didn't understand your question.